# Using perl temporarily in a batch file

Tags: perl, batch-file

I would like to use perl in a batch file then exit perl and continue with the batch code. A small example I would like to achieve :

```
perl do something
echo hello
pause
```

Comment: What's stopping you from doing that?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's ok now... My previous try was unsuccessful.

Comment: If you were successful, post your answer below and accept it. Others may have the same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Perl is installed, there should be no problem:

```
perl -e "print $_ for 1 .. 10"
perl script.pl
```

You might need to specify the full path to perl and the script.pl.

Comment: I guess I had forgotten the option "e" for "one line of program". Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 4):

```
@echo off
perl script.pl
echo hello
pause
```

or

```
@echo off
perl -e" ...code..."
echo hello
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm just reading it wrong but I interpretted the question as asking how to embed perl scripts directly into batch files.

Activeperl adds a bunch of these as .cmd files and there is a [tool](http://search.cpan.org/~nwclark/perl-5.8.9/win32/bin/pl2bat.pl) on cpan for creating them from your perl script.

I also found two [examples](http://www.dostips.com/DtCodeInterfacing.php#Interfacing.Perl) from a quick search that seem to extend the idea a little. They allow you to put the code into the same file and run dos commands before and after the perl call, which is what I thought you were asking.

Here's one of the examples:

```
@rem = 'Perl, ccperl will read this as an array of assignment & skip this block  
@CD /d "%~dp0"  
@perl -s "%~nx0" %*  
@FOR /L %%c in (4,-1,1) do @(TITLE %~nx0 - %%cs to close & ping -n 2 -w 1000 127.0.0.1 NUL)  
@TITLE Press any key to close the window&ECHO.&GOTO:EOF  
@rem ';

#perl script starts below here  
print 'Hi there!  DOS rocks!\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do vice-versa. i.e. Call Batch commands from perl

```
my $cmd = 'some command';
if (system $cmd) {
    print "Error: $? for command $cmd"
}
```

Save this perl script. This should do your job as well.